# asp c# looping through dynamic datatable

Tags: c#, asp.net, foreach, datatable

asp c#
i have a page where user selects an item and its quantity to purchase and next item and so on
all items selected are filled in datatable and shown in gridview
at the end of selecting items
when user clicks process button
i want to insert all items and its quantities in database

on pageload a datatable is empty
on btn_Select_Click i hv filled in few rows
on btn_Process_Click i want to loop through these rows and insert records in db for each row

but it returns zero rows

Comment: It would be helpful to see some of the code.

Comment: [DbDataAdapter.Update Method (DataTable)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z1z2bkx2.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is a little vague.  "but it returns zero rows"... I'm guessing that what you mean is, that in the click handler for your button, when you access your grid object, it has no rows in it?

Remember that each load of the page creates a whole set of brand new webcontrols.  Webcontrol objects are not persisted in memory to be reused on each hit to the page.

If you want the same rows available on this new page that is being rendered after the button click, you have to re-bind your grid.  I'm guessing that isn't happening in your code.